# How to sample N points between 0 and R if they are exponentially distributed?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

The density of my points x $\in$ [0,R] is exponential:
$\rho(x) \approx e^x$

How can I sample N points from there?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an important class of problems, with many different sorts of solutions.  We give a procedure that is general, but has important drawbacks.

A random variable $X$ with density function a constant times $e^x$ on $[0,R]$ and $0$ elsewhere is unlikely to come up in applications. In order for the integral over $[0,R]$ to be $1$, the density function of $X$ will be given by
$$f(x)=\frac{e^x}{e^R-1}$$
on $[0,R]$, and $0$ elsewhere. On the interval $[0,R]$, the cumulative distribution function $F(x)$ is given by
$$F(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{e^R-1}.$$
To simulate, we use independent uniforms $U$ on the interval $[0,1]$, and solve the equation
$$\frac{e^X-1}{e^R-1}=U.$$
We get 
$$X=\ln(1+(e^R-1)U).$$